# Using Perforce (P4) Grep Remotely without Cloning

Tags: grep, perforce

Is there any method of using the p4 grep command line to conduct syntactical searches against the remote perforce repository? I understand p4 grep can be used when cloning a repo to local disk, but this would require hundreds of GBs of diskspace, not to mention the time required to sync that much data. I'd prefer a way of doing this without the requirement to clone source code locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no requirement to clone a local copy to run *any* Perforce command as long as you can connect to the server.

```
p4 set P4PORT=remote.p4.server:1666
p4 set P4USER=your_username
p4 login
p4 grep -e EXPR //depot/path/...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Being a new perforce user, I may be missing something obvious. I went through these steps and received the following:    **p4 grep -e config \\targetrepo**
Path '\\targetrepo' is not under client's root 'c:\Program Files\Perforce'.

Comment: If that's literally what you typed, then you made two typos: (1) Use `//targetrepo`, not `\\targetrepo`. (2) include '/...' at the end as in `p4 grep -e config //targetrepo/...`.